# Has any physicist answered a question citing his own work on PhysicsSE?

Tags: discussion

Imagine if when reading a question about a theory or paper by Michio Kaku, you scrolled down to see an answer "When I wrote this theory, [...]".

I always thought it'd be neat to see something like that here - has it happened?

More specifically, has any question, citing a specific theory or work recieved an answer by someone who self-identifies as being the author of the work / theory in question?

Comment: Not on this site, there's an interesting answer to [Was the reduction in Shor's algorithm originally discovered by Shor?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/25512/) in Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange, by one [Peter Shor](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/1677/peter-shor).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty ...who indirectly has referenced his own work here a number of times, e.g. in [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26983/depolarizing-threshold-for-css-codes).

Comment: The question is slightly unclear. Are you asking for situations where user A asks a question about Dr. B's work, and B shows up and explains it? Or is it OK for A to ask something more general and Prof. Dr. C to chime in and give examples from their own work? There is a slight title/body disconnect in how you phrase it.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Your second example is more of "Hi, Im smart I wrote I paper I'll refernce it so you can admire me" whilst Im asking about "Hi, I see you cited my work, here's the answer to your question." If you read my bottom paragraph I think I really did make this clear by the way.

Comment: @JonathanTodd Not necessarily. In any case, the title could (and should) be improved to better reflect the spirit of the question.

Comment: I mentioned [the second footnote on page 12 of this article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608592v1.pdf) referencing my work in a discussion some time ago somewhere here on StackExchange :) .

Answer (score 10):

A pretty famous guy, [G. 't Hooft](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/11205/g-t-hooft), wrote a response about one of his papers: [Deterministic quantum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18586/deterministic-quantum-mechanics/160193#160193) on this site.

Doing a search of [`"my paper"`](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22my+paper%22) presents a few more users who have at least cited their works in their answers (discounting vixra because it's usually not reputable works hosted there), though not usually the case that the question itself is about their works:

- [Xiao-Gang Wen](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/9444/xiao-gang-wen)

  - https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A9444+my+paper
- [Arnold Neumaier](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/7924/arnold-neumaier)

  - https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A7924+my+paper
- [Luboš Motl](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1236/lubo%C5%A1-motl)

  - https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1236+my+paper

Comment: And my own question was answered with a link to a review article by the answerer: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71654/

Comment: Very good. But I recommend searching with http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1236+%22my+paper%22 etc instead. Adding the quotes takes away a lot of answers where "my" and "paper" appear in different locations in the answer.

Comment: Well, neither am I too shy to mention my articles in my answers when I believe the articles are relevant:-), see, e.g., http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/181073/why-are-complex-fields-in-the-lagrangian or http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31497/maxwells-equations-in-microscopic-and-macroscopic-forms-and-quantization

Comment: I'm a particle physics experimentor so 'my paper' isn't really a thing. I often issue ["full disclosure"](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22full+disclosure%22)'s when I cite a paper that I am party to.